# Monetdb on windows : unable to connect to mserver5 after upgrade

Tags: monetdb

First message on this topic.
-I had an old monetdb installation on my windows laptop
-Did the upgrade in Oct2020-SP5
-It really looks like I can start the server

```
C:\Program Files\MonetDB\MonetDB5\bin>mserver5
# MonetDB 5 server v11.39.17 (Oct2020-SP5)
# Serving database 'demo', using 4 threads
# Compiled for amd64-pc-windows-msvc/64bit
# Found 15.862 GiB available main-memory of which we use 12.928 GiB
# Copyright (c) 1993 - July 2008 CWI.
# Copyright (c) August 2008 - 2021 MonetDB B.V., all rights reserved
# Visit https://www.monetdb.org/ for further information
# Listening for connection requests on mapi:monetdb://localhost:50000/
# MonetDB/GIS module loaded
# MonetDB/SQL module loaded
# MonetDB server is started. To stop server press Ctrl-C.
```

But when I want to use the mclient, it asks the user and password and then... nothing
[here the stupid screen I am blocked in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Fjv.png)
Same thing with an ODBC connection : after a long time, it fails

I have no idea of what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Simon! Is this an existing database or a new one? Also, please try running mclient with the -X option, this makes it trace its interaction with the server, if any interaction occurs

Comment: Hello @JoerivanRuth and thanks. There is an existing database (at least there was an existing database before the upgrade).

I also tried the -X option and nothing more
C:\Program Files\MonetDB\MonetDB5\bin>mclient -X
user(win32):monetd
password:

Best regards,

Simon

Comment: Re @JoerivanRuth
After a long time (maybe 3-4 minutes), I had finally a message "user(win32):monetdb
password:
Challenge string is not valid, it is empty"

Best regards,

Simon

Comment: We couldn't reproduce this with the official binaries. Did you happen to build MonetDB yourself?

Comment: hello @JoerivanRuth. No, I didn't, I'm not that good :D . Can it be something linked to security (a firewall or an antivirus blocking something?)

I think I will make a reinstall. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Reinstallation done, same result :(

Comment: Hello,

Finally, after several reboots and a windows crash, it works ! However, is it possible to know where this error message can came ?

Best regards,

Simon